# AWK associative array, mapping or hash map

Tags: awk, mapping, associative-array

Suppose I have two files:

file1 - map.txt

```
1, 178246
2, 289789
3, 384275
4, 869282
```

file2 - relation.txt

```
178246, 289789
384275, 178246
384275, 869282
```

Expected results are:

```
1, 2
3, 1
3, 4
```

But the results I got using the following code were:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{map[$2]=$1} {$1=map[$1];$2=map[$2];print $0}' map.txt relation.txt

  2,
  1,
  4,
```

It was confused when I swapped the columns in map.txt like this:

```
178246, 1
289789, 2
384275, 3
869282, 4
```

relation.txt doesn't change

The results became:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{map[$1]=$2} {$1=map[$1];$2=map[$2];print $0}' map.txt relation.txt

1,
3,
3,
```

It seems that something wrong near {$1=map[$1];$2=map[$2];print $0}

Comment: if I use some real name like tony, jerry, frank instead of uid 178246, 289789, etc, my code works perfectly, I do not know why it doesn't work when I use numbers instead of strings as the index of the associative array

Comment: Great!It works. I use "|" instead of "," and it works perfectly. Thank you so much Shellter.

Comment: how can i give you a answer score? lol, a nice answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the leading space in both files in column 2.

And do yourself a favor and switch to something besides commas for `FS`. The Tab char is good because most input screens use tab to move to the next field, so it shouldn't be in your data. The `|` char is nice because it is visual and very unlikely to be in your input.

You could build a 'trap' to find records without the right number of fields like this:

```
awk -F"|" -v expectFldCnt=2 '{
   if (NF==expectFldCnt) { print ":everything OK" ; }
    else { print "ERR: " NF "!=" expectFldCnt  ":" $0 > "errorFile" }
    }' \
  map.txt relation.txt
```

IHTH

Answer (score 5):

```
awk  -F"[, ]" 'NR==FNR {m[$3]=$1;next};{print m[$1]",",m[$3]}' map.txt relations.txt
```