# How can I make a script that calls awk in a loop over k/v pairs faster?

Tags: bash, awk, processing-efficiency

I have numerous amounts of text files that I would like to loop through. While looping I would like to find lines that match a list of strings and extract each to a separate folder. I have a variable "ij" that need to be split into "i" and "j" to match two columns. For example 2733 needs to be split into 27 and 33. The script searches each text file and extracts every line that has an i and j of 2733.

The problem here is that I have nearly 100 different strings, so it takes about 35 hours to get through all these strings.

Is there any way to extract all of the variables to separate files in just one loop? I am trying to loop through a text file, extract all the lines that are in my list of strings and output them to their own folder, then move onto the next text file.

I am currently using the "awk" command to accomplish this.

```sh
list="2741 2740 2739 2738 2737 2641 2640 2639 2638 2541 2540 2539 2538 2441 2440 2439 2438 2341 2340 2339  2241 2240 2141" 

for string in $list
    do
     for i in  ${string:0:2}
      do
       for j in ${string:2:2}
        do 

          awk -v i=$i -v j=$j '$2==j && $3==i {print $0}' $datadir/*.txt >"${fileout}${i}_${j}_Output.txt"

done
done
done
```

Comment: Generally speaking, don't run ever run awk inside a loop; instead, *put the loop inside awk*.

Comment: ...in the immediate case, it looks to me like you could do just one pass through *all* your files, and have that single awk pass write multiple output files. If you create a single lookup table inside your awk script for the `i` and `j` values you want to match, then for each line of input you can figure out if that line matches a value you want, and open and write to the appropriate output file; unlike bash, (GNU) awk automatically maintains a cache of file descriptors for recently-used output files, so it won't literally re-open the output file for each write when done properly.

Comment: Great suggestions, but I am unsure how to put the loop inside awk. Also how would I go about creating a lookup table?

Comment: The biggest problem is that for each loop each loop each loop you re-read all whole files. It should be done in a single pass - input/output operations are usually the bottleneck.

Comment: "How would I go about creating a lookup table?" -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105473/awk-associative-array-mapping for an example. (I used the word "map", but awk calls the data structures arrays, just arrays that happen to have strings as indices).

Comment: ...and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077631/is-it-possible-to-print-different-lines-to-different-output-files-using-awk re: selecting an output file.

Comment: rather than `for i in ${string:0:2}; do ... done`, just write `i=${string:0:2}`.  Similarly for `j`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did this:

```
# for each 4 digits in the list
# add "a[" and "];" before and after the four numbers
# so awk array is "a[2741]; a[2740]; a[2739]; ...."
awkarray=$(awkarray=$(<<<"$list" sed -E 's/[0-9]{4}/a[&];/g')
awk -vfileout="$fileout" '
  BEGIN {'"$awkarray"'}
  $2 $3 in a { 
    print $0 > fileout $2 "_" $3 "_Output.txt"
  }
' "$datadir"/*.txt
```

So first I transform the list to load it as an array in awk. The array has only indexes, so I can check if an index exists in an array, the array elements have no values. Then I simply check if the concatenation of $2 and $3 exists in the array, if it exists, the output is redirected to proper filename.

Remember to quote your variables. `$datadir/*.txt` may not work, when `datadir` contains spaces, do `"$datadir"/*.txt`. The newlines in awk script 
above can be removed, so if you prefer a oneliner:

```
awk -vfileout="$fileout" 'BEGIN {'"$(<<<"$list" sed -E 's/[0-9]{4}/a[&];/g')"'} $2 $3 in a { print $0 > fileout $2 "_" $3 "_Output.txt" }' "$datadir"/*.txt
```

Comment: This has been MUCH more efficient. With just these few strings in the list the script has gone from over 2 hours to 7 minutes. Thank you very much, I am still learning Bash!